# Create AMI when EC2 instance shuts down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to create AMI when a instance is terminated/shuts down to back it up. I setup a CloudWatch rule on EC2 Instance State Changed event to create AMI via SSM Run Command (Target document is AWS-RunShellScript(Linux)). It works fine, if I provide a hardcoded instance id to command parameter.

```
/home/ec2-user/createImage.sh i-123456
```

This rule needs to be applied to all instances. I need to get instance-id dynamically from source and send it to target. I tried Input Transformer but its not getting the data from source. Dynamic parameters like {{variable Name}} also not working. Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Once it's terminated it's gone. It is too late to back it up at that point.

Comment: I am running the script at "shutting down/stopped" state currently.

Comment: Stopped instances still exist and can be restarted. Terminated instance no longer exist. Stopped instance == turning the power off to your laptop. Terminated instance == smashing your laptop with a hammer and throwing the pieces in a dumpster. You can backup a stopped instance because the instance, and in particular the EBS volume, still exists. You can't backup a terminated instance.

Comment: @Mark B: I know the difference between various states. I need help to create AMIs from cloudwatch rules dynamically. If I know how to extarct instance id from source and how to send it to target, that will solve my problem.

Comment: Your question specifically states "create AMI when a instance is terminated". I'm just commenting to let you know that that part of your question isn't something that can be answered, because it isn't possible. The part about running a backup automatically on shutdown is totally possible and I look forward to seeing answers to that part of your question.

Comment: @Mark B: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the headline.

Comment: I am having the same issue while trying to perform some actions using a lifecycle hook for a terminating instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an Amazon CloudWatch Events rule:

[image: Amazon CloudWatch Events rule]

You can have the rule trigger an AWS Lambda function that triggers the snapshot. When the Lambda function is triggered, the following information is passed to the function:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "01345791-08ce-baaf-78f5-437aca50f13c",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2017-09-12T00:28:55Z",
  "region": "ap-southeast-2",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:instance/i-0cf605453b22f703e"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": "i-0cf605453b22f703e",
    "state": "stopped"
  }
}
```

Note that the Instance ID is passed with the message, so you can use this in the `CreateSnapshot` command within the Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John. I setup a Lambda function as a target in CloudWatch and successfully tested it. This [link](http://powerupcloud.azurewebsites.net/2016/10/15/serverless-automate-ami-creation-and-deletion-using-aws-lambda/) has the code to create AMI.